# How to find the leftmost 6 bits of a number

Tags: c

I am working on a project and it asks me to find the instruction and register from the given input using bit operators. For example:

Given: 0x316ac000 => The output will be **lt** **R5** **R10** **R11**

R: represent the register

I tried to convert it on paper. The way I did it was first convert that input to binary (ignore the 0x), then I group the left most 6 bits which give me a decimal = 12, 12 is **sub** base on the table.

So how can I actually code it? or the logic on this

Thank you for your help!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you read the chapter in any C book/tutorial describing bitwise operators? These are basic shift and mask operators that will be covered in any good reference material.

Comment: I assume your class is about bitwise operations? AND? OR?

Comment: given 32 or more bit variable input: `(input >> 26) & 0x3f` will give you 6 bit value for opcode

Comment: @IłyaBursov What is the reason to & with that mask?

Comment: @user1738539 in case of 64 bit input variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary is a notation for *humans*.

To get bits from a number, use the bit shift and bit mask operations. For example, to get bits 3-5 of a value:

```
(value >> 3) & 0x7
```

That is, shift right three bits (to get rid of bits 0, 1, and 2) and bit mask (logical AND) with a 7, which equals 0x111.

You can compute a mask by a bit shift and subtract:

```
(1 << N_bits) - 1
```

So we can write a function:

```
unsigned long get_bits( int start, int stop, unsigned long value )
{
  unsigned long mask = (1UL << (stop - start + 1)) - 1;
  return (value >> start) & mask;
}
```

BTW, bit shifts are tricky with integers. Use unsigned values.